# Best algorithm for reinforcement learning for a four in a row game

Tags: java, reinforcement-learning

What is the best algorithm for reinforcement learning for a four in a row game.
I want to build a four in a row game that will use one of the RL algorithms to play:
Q-Learning, MinMax etc.

What is the best one to use considering I am using Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MinMax is pretty good for that game. The real question is how good will be your eurhistic function to determine what's the "value" of a certain move.

Comment: How do you suggest to build the heuristic function?

Answer (score 0):

MinMax isn't usually considered to be a reinforcement learning algorithm, but it probably is the 'best' (depending on what you mean by that) for Connect 4.

Connect 4 has been [solved](http://tromp.github.io/c4/c4.html) (on many different sizes of board) for nearly three decades now.  The solver has even been used as a processor benchmark known as [Fhourstones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fhourstones) and the [source](https://github.com/qu1j0t3/fhourstones) in Java (and C) is freely available.

If your aim is to learn about Q-learning (in tabular form), REINFORCE, or some of the more modern reinforcement learning algorithms such as Deep Q-learning using neural networks (DQN) or Action Advantage Actor Critic (A3C) then I've no doubt that these can all be applied successfully to Connect 4.  I'd recommend a good book such as Barto & Sutton's Reinforcement Learning.  At the time of writing, a [draft of the 2nd edition](http://incompleteideas.net/sutton/book/bookdraft2017june19.pdf) is freely available in PDF form.

However, if your aim is simply to have a best player, then you'll struggle to beat the perfect play of Fhourstones.